# List available solvers in JuMP

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I installed `JuMP` and tried to initialize a `Model()`, while doing so I would like to specify the solver based on what is available. For this how could I get a list of available solvers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of solvers currently supported by the julia optimisation eco-system is maintained on the `juliaopt` website: http://www.juliaopt.org/

At the time of writing, it included a long list of commercial and open source solvers:

*Clp, Cbc, GLPK, ECOS, SCS, CPLEX, Gurobi, FICO Xpress, Mosek, NLopt, Ipopt, Bonmin, Couenne, Artelys Knitro*

Note that each of these solvers come with their own Julia wrappers, which need to be installed in addition to installing the `JuMP` package. `Pkg.add(Clp)` will, for example, install the `Clp` Julia wrapper. For wrappers around open source solvers, such as Clp, the underlying solver will *usually* be downloaded and installed as part of the Julia package installation.

Obviously, for the commercial solvers, one needs to buy a license and install the solver program.

Comment: Thanks! Installing the wrappers too seems to be easy, e.x. 'Pkg.add(Clp)' installs the CLP wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @Abhijith , I've added a reference to Pkg.add in the answer.

Comment: Note that juliaopt is now JuMP, and the link is outdated. As of 6/1/2021 I believe the best link is https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/installation/#Supported-solvers.